# Put a list of tuples into one tuple separated by comma to export into SQL

Tags: python, tuples

I am hitting and looping through an API to collect various data into a variable called `data`. If I do `print(data)` I get the following:

```py
('1111', 11, 'Test1', '2020-16-09', '123')
('2222', 22, 'Test2', '2020-16-09', '234')
('3333', 33, 'Test3', '2020-16-09', '345')
```

When I do `print(type(data))` I get the following:

```py
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
```

I need to put these tuples into one tuple separating each with a comma to look something like the below.

```py
( 
    ('1111', 11, 'Test1', '2020-16-09', '123'),
    ('2222', 22, 'Test2', '2020-16-09', '234'),
    ('3333', 33, 'Test3', '2020-16-09', '345') 
)
```

This it to allow me to export the data into SQL using `cursor.executemany`

Comment: How are the separate tuples held now? `tuple(your_tuples)` should work if they're already in an iterable.

Comment: We would need to see more code for context, but why not just define a list outside the loop and add each tuple to it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a function `api(x)` that returns you the tuple for input `x`, and you know all the `x` you need to query, which is from a list `X=[x1, x2, ...]`, then you can get a *tuple of tuple* by this:

```
tuple_of_tuples = tuple(api(x) for x in X)
```

but in the case of `cursor.executemany()`, many database library accepts an iterable as input, in that case, you can use a generator instead, which saves you memory in keeping all tuples:

```
generator_of_tuples = (api(x) for x in X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help, after doing some more digging around this is how I managed to get the data how I needed it.

```
jsondata = (multiple tuples) #my data from looping an API
    if b == 0: #b is my loop through the API
        finaldata = (jsondata,)
    else:
        finaldata = (jsondata,) + finaldata
```